# I want to display the trend of my sensor readings in my aquaponic system set in the Firebase Realtime Database for every trials we finished

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, sensors, linegraph

I want to display the trend of our five sensor readings in our aquaponic system set in the Firebase Realtime Database for every trials we finished.

I tried asking ChatGPT but it does not give any concrete solutions. I am expecting it to display in a different line graphs, showing timestamps and the readings within that time, and it will be displayed in our Flutter Android Mobile App.